# Javafx Scene Builder show web page

Tags: javafx, html

My question is possible with Javafx Scene Builder show the webpage or html file?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not "browse" the web with JavaFX Scene Builder directly, no.

But you can add the WebView Control element to your scene graph and use this component to browse the internet or local HTML files, see the corresponding documentation of [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's work.
First step is build to the Scene Builder the AnchorePane thereon StackPane thereon WebView.
The code:

```
@FXML
private WebView web;

@FXML
private StackPane root;

public void initialize() {

        WebEngine engine = web.getEngine();
        //engine.load("https://www.google.com/maps");
        final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("GoogleMapsV3.html");
        engine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        root.getChildren().add(web);    

    }
```

Thanks a lot.